# Where is BatchNorm performed in ResNeXT https://github.com/facebookresearch/ResNeXt neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, residuals, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization, residual-networks

In the original paper that described ResNeXT (variation of Resnet) at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.05431.pdf.

On Page-5 top right column, it says:

> ReLU is performed right after eachBN, expect for the output of the
>   block where ReLU is per-formed after the adding to the shortcut,
>   following [14].

This sentence doesn't make sense, esp the part after comma "expect for the output of....".

- Could someone explain what this sentence means?
- Where is BN performed?

Comment: "expect" is probably a typo of "except." Once you make that correction, I think the description is clear.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica ah, i see. i was wondering, how could it have been published with such a blatant typo? i looked up about what 'arxiv' is and not sure if it's a reputable publication or not, but lots of ML/AI work seems to be published there. what is it?

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica i'm new to ai/ml. where do generally AI/ML people publish there new topologies? how come 'arxiv' published so many of papers for new architectures, like resnet, resnext etc.?

Comment: ArXiv is journal preprints. This means the articles haven’t been published yet. Typos are the least of your worries.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica what does journal preprint mean? i'm unfamiliar with publication terminology. if it's not a journal, which journal publishes them after 'preprint' at arXiv?

Comment: It's more-or-less a draft that the author intends to eventually submit to a journal, or already has submitted. No *particular* journal publishes arXiv papers -- it's just a collection of papers that *might be* printed in a journal somewhere in the world in the future. So, on the one hand, arXiv allows you to read a paper today that might not appear until two or three years in the future, because peer review is slow. On the other hand, the paper might not be published because it's flawed, not novel, or any other reason. Anyway, "What is arXiv?" and "What's a preprint?" aren't stats questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a typo; "expect" is likely supposed to be "except." Once you make that correction, I think the description is clear.

Comment: Yes, that may explain it. This question seems legit, so if you downvoted can you say why so I can edit it accordingly?

Comment: I didn't, but I've noticed that it's very rare for any of the answers to your questions to have any upvotes. Perhaps you should interrogate your own voting practices?

Comment: I didn't vote on my own post, so I'm not sure how my voting practice is relevant, or am I missing something. I already said I can edit the post, and the question in this thread was downvoted even though it seems a reasonable question for this forum.

Comment: You are, however, allowed to vote on **answers** to your posts. You're missing the word "answers" from my previous comment.

Comment: ah, i see. i didn't see why someone would down-vote the question for that reason alone though when no clear answer. the ones that resolve the issue i try to vote when i get to them eventually but i'm not here all the time and not all answers always resolve the question. in this case this answer does resolve the issue as it seems to be due to a typo in publication. i'll upvote it.

Comment: When there's no comment with a downvote, one can only speculate as to the reason for it. FWIW, the tooltip for a downvote on a question says "This question does not show any research effort; it is not clear or not useful."

Comment: This question for example cites accurate details from the paper so it does seem to show research effort and the topic of resneXT being an influential variant of well-known resnet has been useful to the community, in this case as evidence by potential incorrect printing of the paper. so in my understanding the issue regarding why such questions were downvoted even with research effort stands. due to the downvote sometime the automated system seems to affect ability to post on the forum.